# Howto invite friends to an application with an deep link to a page?

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, deep-linking

we develop an Facebook application and to encourage others to participate, we want to let the user sent an URL to its friends in order to get help. The URL should open the page with the application in the canvas pointing directly to the deep resource.

How can I achieve the above?

Answer (score 0):

Try out the Requests 2.0 . 
You can find the documentation here https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/464

Phani...